# When we have constructor provided by compiler then why do we use our own constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

When we have constructor provided by compiler then why do we use our own constructor?

Comment: We have functions already provided by the compiler (e.g. `_exit`); why do we write our own functions? We also have variables already defined by the compiler `int argc`, why do we define our own variables?

Comment: Because the constructors provided by the compiler can't always do what we want to do.

Comment: Not a bad question, seeing code which is doing the work of the default constructor. On the other hand, please get informed.

Comment: We don't, unless we need it to do something that the provided constructor doesn't.

Comment: @RSahu Answers in comments grrrr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the constructors provided by the compiler can't always do what we want to do.

Comment: @Dieter: The OP's C++ book elaborates.

Answer (score 1):

Say your class has an owning pointer. Is the compiler supposed to know what you are going to initialize it with?

Comment: sir i have not yet studied pointers my exams are coming and I need help with this question i am student at University of Sargodha, Sargodha, Pakistan. can you please tell like you are telling a person who is starting with c++ programming